# Variable opacity within a WPF application

Tags: wpf

My problem is:

I have a Canvas which covers part of my Window. The Opacity of the canvas is set to less than 1, i.e. I can view the controls under the Canvas. What I would like to do is place a control, any control, say a Button, on the canvas and not have that Button semitransparent. Is this possible using WPF?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the alpha in the color of the canvas.